# Removing images from app.component.html removes html elements from another component.html file

Tags: html, css, angular

I have two images in app.component.html file the file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="noscroll" [ngClass]="{noscroll: noScroll}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-navbar> </app-navbar>
    <div class="homedisplays">
    <img class="displayimage" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETsekJKsr3M/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i have a div in another navbar.component.html file which implements ngClass to make the div visible when a button is clicked. This works fine when the images in the app.component file are there, but once i delete the images from the app.component.html file the div no longer displays as visible when the button is clicked.

the images are in a div and these are the css classes.

```
.homedisplays{
  position:  relative;
  top: 15%;

}

.displayimage{
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}
```

I have tried adding the images and classes to another component, but i get the same problem.

Comment: Is this app.component.html I’m looking at..?

Comment: @MikeOne yes this is the app.component.html and app.component.css file

Comment: In that case.. you might want to remove the html, head and body tags. Those already exist in your index.html..

Comment: @MikeOne I just tried that but still get the same issue.